# How can I get just the expiry date of a domain name using Indy in Delphi 10.3.3 Pro?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio, indy-9

How can I get just the expiry date of a domain name using Indy's `TIdWhois` component?

I don't want to get the full WHOIS data, but only the expiry date.

I used this code:

```pascal
IdWhois1.Host:= edit1.Text;
memo1.Lines.Text := IdWhois1.WhoIs (edit2.Text);
```

This show the full WHOIS data.

Answer (score 2):

You can't: the [WHOIS protocol stores data in a human-readable format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS), which is why you only have text and can't specifically query a date and then even get it in a non-text type.

Parse the text yourself: find the line that matches most of what you expect, then convert the date from text into your favorite datatype. Expect WHOIS results that have no or an empty expiry line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function RegExMatch( aInput : string; aPattern : string; 
                      aInversed : Boolean) : String');
writeln(RegExMatch(IdWhois1.WhoIs('domain ibm.com'), 
                     '.*Registry Expiry Date.*', false));
```